# SELECT TOP 10 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have built an SQL Query that returns me the top 10 customers which have the highest outstanding. The oustanding is on product level (each product has its own outstanding).

[image]

Untill now everything works fine, my only problem is that if a certain customer has more then 1 product then the second product or more should be categorized under the same customer_id like in the second picture (because the first product that has the highest outstanding contagions the second product that may have a lower outstanding that the other 9 clients of top 10).
How can I modify my query in order to do that? Is it possible in SQL Server 2012?

[image]

My query is:

```
select top 10 CUSTOMER_ID
             ,S90T01_GROSS_EXPOSURE_THSD_EUR
             ,S90T01_COGNOS_PROD_NAME
             ,S90T01_DPD_C
             ,PREVIOUS_BUCKET_DPD_REP
             ,S90T01_BUCKET_DPD_REP
from [dbo].[DM_07MONTHLY_DATA]
where S90T01_CLIENT_SEGMENT = 'PI'
      and YYYY_MM = '2017_01'
group by CUSTOMER_ID
        ,S90T01_GROSS_EXPOSURE_THSD_EUR
        ,S90T01_COGNOS_PROD_NAME
        ,S90T01_DPD_C
        ,PREVIOUS_BUCKET_DPD_REP
        ,S90T01_BUCKET_DPD_REP
order by S90T01_GROSS_EXPOSURE_THSD_EUR desc;
```

Comment: [why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: So do you want the 10 highest customers by total `outstanding` across all products or the 10 highest individual products?

Comment: @iamdave I want the top 10 highest customers by outstanding, but if possible the outstanding should be split for each product (like in the second picture).

Comment: So, the highest by *total* `outstanding` across all products, with each of the customers products listed as individual rows?  Also, your `group by` suggests that you have a lot of data duplication in the `monthly_data` table?  If not, you don't need that `group by`.

Comment: @iamdave The "S90T01_GROSS_EXPOSURE_THSD_EUR" field shows the outstanding for each client on product bases. If a certain client has more than 1 product, but the last product has a lower outstanding than the other 9 clients in top 10, I want this product to be listed on top 10. So that means there will be more then 10 records in the output.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate the top Customers first, then pull out all their products.  You can do this with a Common Table Expression.

As you haven't provided any test data this is untested, but I think it will work for you:

```
with top10 as
(
    select top 10 CUSTOMER_ID
                 ,sum(S90T01_GROSS_EXPOSURE_THSD_EUR) as TOTAL_S90T01_GROSS_EXPOSURE_THSD_EUR
    from [dbo].[DM_07MONTHLY_DATA]
    where S90T01_CLIENT_SEGMENT = 'PI'
          and YYYY_MM = '2017_01'
    group by CUSTOMER_ID
    order by TOTAL_S90T01_GROSS_EXPOSURE_THSD_EUR desc
)
select m.CUSTOMER_ID
        ,m.S90T01_GROSS_EXPOSURE_THSD_EUR
        ,m.S90T01_COGNOS_PROD_NAME
        ,m.S90T01_DPD_C
        ,m.PREVIOUS_BUCKET_DPD_REP
        ,m.S90T01_BUCKET_DPD_REP
from [dbo].[DM_07MONTHLY_DATA] m
    join top10 t
        on m.CUSTOMER_ID = t.CUSTOMER_ID
order by t.TOTAL_S90T01_GROSS_EXPOSURE_THSD_EUR desc
    ,m.S90T01_GROSS_EXPOSURE_THSD_EUR;
```

Comment: thank you very much for the support. In fact the query is showing the following error message: Invalid column name 'S90T01_GROSS_EXPOSURE_THSD_EUR'.

Comment: @Marin  Ah, wrong alias in the `order by`,  try now.

Comment: thank you soooo much :) You are a life savior! I edited a little bit the above query so I could get the information only for a specific YEAR_MONTH, because if you don't specify it it will show the entire history of the client. Best regards from me :)